# Should question's be forced to have a set of premises?

Tags: discussion

Today is the first day I've seen the philosophy stack exchange.  I'm casually interested in the topics here, but my main problem with participating is that most people don't provide a premise or properly define their question.

For example I see many posts with `God` in them, but they don't define what they mean by `God`.  I see posts where people ask if `X` would be wrong but they don't talk about how they define right or wrong.

Should people be required to better define posed questions?  Or is this site meant to be loose?

I'm not saying it should be either way, just trying to gauge the community.

Comment: Currently, [we're actually still debating](http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/2820/2953) - this is not *exactly* your question, but very similar. Good question though.

Comment: I personally do not applaud so many users posting God thing...though I don't deny it. You can not tell anything, if you may not misunderstand me though,,..........

Comment: Isn't it **interesting** to see over 3K people jamming into this http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/22697/is-god-subject-to-logic question **within 2 days** and talking you know whatever it is including mine which may sound to them like a munbo-jumbo logic and the average visitor as far as I know is 30-70 a day on a topic? And then I just finally **gave up** speaking itself. ------------

Comment: Getting upovote there ↑

Comment: I am sorry, I tried to mean, by getting upvote there ↑, there seem to be a lot of people who would like to **continue** to discuss. Well then, it's according to the standard by the moderator, I think sure there should be some standard we can comprehend enough with, personally.

Answer (score 3):

Definitions are important, and people should be stating them as often as possible. Questions which are unclear for this reason will ultimately be downvoted and/or closed, so I think it works out anyways (the OP will be notified and forced to be more specific or the question will remain closed and eventually deleted).

Definitely do comment on a post if you think definitions should be added, but we don't "force" anyone to do anything in a strict sense. We do *highly recommend* things though (with the idea that the question will be closed/deleted if the recommendation is not followed), so that might be basically the same thing.